# SQL Server 2005 -- Not Able To Export Using Management Studio Express

Tags: sql-server, ssms, export, import

I heard this was not available with the free express version.

I need to move a moderately sized database to another computer.
How can I most easily accomplish this task?

We are not in a position to buy any software at the moment.

Thanks for any suggestions! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default there's no tools visible in the IDE but you can access the DTSWizard to do import/export if you've got the SQL with Advanced Services installed (free).

You'll find it in Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\DTSWizard.exe - I add it as an External Tool in the Tools menu for ease.

But if you're just moving the whole DB then then joeqwerty's options should do you fine...

Answer (score 1):

Backup and Restore? Detach and Attach?